# What is the name of this whorled-leaf tree in India?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location: South India

Month: June

Season: Rainy

[image]

Branch Distribution:

[image]

Leaf of the tree:

[image]

Comment: The leaves look like those of a Pittosporum

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Bucida molineti* also called geometry tree